# AngularJS - reset form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form with animated place holders; driven by a directive (*hasfocus*) this binds blur, change, and focus events. This works fine however when I reset the form the view does not update, I was expecting the change event to trigger.

If you enter text and click login, the text will be removed but the active *class* will not be removed from the label.

#### Controller

```
$scope.send = function(){
    //1. ajax to send data
    //2. if response is true reset form... 
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.username = "";
};
```

#### Directive

```
app.directive('hasfocus', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('blur', function() {
          if(!element[0].value){
            element.parent().find('label').removeClass('active');
          }
      });
      element.bind('change', function() {
          if(!element[0].value){
            element.parent().find('label').removeClass('active');
          }
      });
      element.bind('focus', function() {
        element.parent().find('label').addClass('active');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frippa/vdzqh7pf/10/)

Thanks

Comment: have you considered using the newer angular constructs for `ngClass`? `.ng-pristine`, `.ng-dirty`, `.ng-valid`, `.ng-invalid` all css classes you can set without having to use a directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a [working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/codeepic/vdzqh7pf/9/) for you with minimal changes to your code.
First, you need to send an event from your controller to notify the directive:

```
$scope.$broadcast('remove.class');
```

Then, in the directive, you listen to that event and take action:

```
//private function
function removeClass(element){
    element.parent().find('label').removeClass('active');
}

//when remove.class event is broadcast from controller, the fn() will be triggered
scope.$on('remove.class', function(){
    removeClass(element);
});
```

Comment: I edited my answer and the link points to the correct and functioning code solution.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following changes to your example:

- **Use a `<form>` tag** for the login section
- When resetting the form, call [**`.$setPristine()`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) on the form to reset dirty flags.

A working example for a form reset can be found on [AngularjsHub](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/formreset/)